# Loading Partial View using Ajax.ActionLink in MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to load a partialview in Visual studio using the following method in my controller:

```
public ActionResult ListLocations(int SelectedYear, int continentId, int countryId, string search)
        {
            ViewBag.SchoolYear = SelectedYear;
            IEnumerable<ClimateChart> locationList = repository.FindLocationsByCountryID(continentId, countryId);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                locationList = repository.FindLocationsByCountryID(continentId, countryId)
                    .Where(c => c.Location.ToLower().Contains(search));
            };

            LocationListViewModel model = new LocationListViewModel
            {
                Locations = locationList
            };

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("NoLocationsInCountryErrorPartial");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

This is the html page:

```
@model p2groep11.Net.ViewModels.CountryListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Countries";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Countries</h2>
<div id="partialdiv"></div>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ListCountries", "Continent", FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <div>
        Land: @Html.TextBox("Search")
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </div>
    }
</p>

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Countries)
    {
        <div>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(@item.Name, "ListLocations", new { Selectedyear = @ViewBag.SchoolYear, continentId = item.Continent.ContinentID, countryId = item.CountryID }, new AjaxOptions
               {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                   UpdateTargetId = "partialdiv"
               })
        </div>       
    }
</div>
```

When I click on a country that has locations in it, I get the page with the locations. This works as intended.
However when I click on a country that has no locations, I should remain on the page and receive an error (i.e. the partial view). Now I just go to the page of that country.

I suspect there is something wrong with the Ajax.Actionlink but I can't figure out what.

I have installed the Ajax unobtrusive nuget package and included the script in the layout file.

Comment: You always return     `return PartialView("NoLocationsInCountryErrorPartial"); `    if is an ajax petition, why?

Comment: Have you tried to call your action by pure AJAX?

Comment: I just used some example code i found when googling for partial views and ajax. There is nearly no documentation (that is, i found none). Didnt try pure ajax

Comment: I resolved it using TempData, this is way better in this situation.

Comment: @HardUser posting an answer to your own question that demonstrates how you used TempData in your application to solve your problem would be helpful to other users, gracias.

Comment: I have done this but not with ajax, do you want me to post my solution anyway?